# Fermat's factorization method: why are "a" or "b" always divisible by 3 if "c" and "d" are prime?

Tags: prime-factorization

I was playing around with Fermat's factorization method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method) where the factors are prime and noticed that either a or b is always divisible by 3.  Eg.  From that page, N=5959 and a=80 and b=21. This isn't the only example - for every other example I found this was true.

Why is this true?  Or can someone provide an example where it's not true? (I never found one.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume that $N \bmod 3 \ne 0.$  Otherwise there are counter-examples: $N=15=3\times 5 \rightarrow a=4, b=1$ or $N=21=3\times 7 \rightarrow a=5, b=2$ etc.

Let $N \bmod 3 \ne 0, \; N = a^2-b^2$. Assume both $a,b$ are not divisible by $3.$ So you have $a\equiv\pm 1 \bmod 3$ and $ b\equiv\pm 1 \bmod 3$. Then
$a^2\equiv1 \bmod 3,$  $\;b^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $N = a^2 - b^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 3$. **Contradiction!**